# After applying for a downgrade from basic to free, the Twitter API Endpoint which is supported even in free tier stopped working

Tags: twitter

1.I joined the free tier of the new Twitter API plan around April 30, 2023, created a project, and linked an existing App to it.

2.After linking, I was able to access the GET /2/user/me endpoint without any problems.

3.I found that the App has been suspended on June 20th.
Moreover, the App was no longer associated with the project and was moved to the standalone app.
Accessing the GET /2/user/me endpoint was also giving an error.
Here is the error.

```
{ "title": "Unauthorized", "type": "about:blank", "status": 401, "detail": "Unauthorized" }
```

4.https://twittercommunity.com/t/my-both-apps-suspended-one-for-login-other-for-autotweeting-api-policy-support-form-doesnt-work/191732
According to the information in , I found a description that changing the tier may cause the App to be unlocked the suspension, so I changed the tier from free to basic.

5.As a result, the App suspension has been released.

6.After I re-attached it to the project, I could access the GET /2/user/me endpoint without issue.

7.After that, I downgraded the plan from basic to free to save money. Then, access to the GET /2/user/me endpoint resulted in an error again.
This time, the app is not SUSPENDED.
However, the App is not tied to the project and moved to standalone app.

8.After I re-attached it to the project, nothing changed and GET /2/user/me continued to results in an error.

GET /2/user/me is supported even in free tier. strange.

9.GET /2/user/me endpoint returns the following error.

```
{
    "client_id": "xxxx",
    "detail": "When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.",
    "registration_url": "https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview",
    "title": "Client Forbidden",
    "required_enrollment": "Appropriate Level of API Access",
    "reason": "client-not-enrolled",
    "type": "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden"
}
```

I don't know what is wrong.

The link to Twitter's support form redirects to a different place than expected and does not work.
Also, is it possible to solve the problem by upgrading again? I thought, but the upgrade button itself is not displayed in the developer portal, and I can't do this either.
I want some solution.

Comment: I'm experiencing something similar: I find my previously-suspended (now OK) app gets repeatedly removed from its project and converted to a standalone app, which causes API calls to fail. Happened frequently over the last few weeks, error first seen June 15. Each time, moving the standalone app back inside the project makes it work.